# How do you alleviate stale data in a multi-user web application?

Tags: web-applications, user-experience, persistence

Displayed data can be changed in the underlying database by any user. How do you show the change to all the other users?

For instance, I have database tables for building and associated rooms. Any user can bring up the lists in their browser and edit. So if user A changes the capacity of room 123 in building X from 30 to 40, but user B has building and room previously loaded into their browser.

How do I...

1. even know that the change has occurred in user B's browser.
2. push the change at the user B.

Via...

1. locking? In other words, prevent concurrent editing.
2. polling? Periodically asking the database if a change has occurred?

Or do I just pretend it doesn't matter and expect the odds of it being an issue are so low that I ignore it?

Comment: Via... 3. client side listener?

Comment: Is the concern that the other user will see the wrong data or make changes based on the stale data a.k.a 'dirty write' or both?

Comment: @JimmyJames Both.

Answer (score 6):

There are two issues here:

1. You don't want a overwrite changes made by one user with changes and old data from another user.
2. You don't want users viewing and making decision based on old data.

The first issue is crucial and can be addressed without dealing with 2.  What I would recommend here is generally called 'optimistic locking'.  You assume that you will usually not have any such collisions where two users retrieve the same version of a record and both try to modify it.  However, there are mechanisms built into the update that will prevent a dirty write from happening if the scenario arises.  The basic shape of the solution is to store a version number on the record.  When the client attempts to change the record, it includes the version that it retrieved.  Then on the update, you compare the version on the record with what is provided by the client.  It it matches, you increment the version as part of the change.  If it doesn't match, no update is made.  You report this back to the user.  How much work you put into helping the user deal with this error is something you need to determine.

An easy way to do this in a relational DB is to include the version number in the `WHERE` clause of the update statement.  If the version on the record doesn't match, the update will modify zero records.

The second issue is probably less severe.  This is a problem that could indicate using [websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).  Essentially, whenever an update is made, you notify all the clients.  If a client is viewing that same record, you inform the user and/or refresh the view.  I would recommend using a library that helps with the websocket client as there are many browser idiosyncrasies to deal with.

Be clear that you can't solve for this entirely.  A user can view a record, make a decision based on what they see and the moment they walk off to act upon it, the record is updated.  All you can do is deliver the data as soon as it is available.